# Wordpress: .addClass when specific data attribute in same row

Tags: jquery, custom-data-attribute

I want to add a class when a data attribute is in that row. As example:

```html
<div id="pgc-13-1-0" class="panel-grid-cell" data-sticky="1">
```

When `data-sticky="1"` is in that row, I want to add a `class` for example `"icetexsticky"`. I tried the following jquery code:

```js
$('[data-sticky~="1"]').each(function( index ) {
    $($this).addClass("icetexsticky")
});
```

But this isn't working. When `data-sticky="1"` isn't in that row, there is no need for an `.addClass`

How can I do this?

Comment: *"But this isn't working."* Isn't working how? Other than what looks like a typo (`$this` rather than `this`), that should work, though it's unnecessarily complex; just `$('[data-sticky~="1"]').addClass("icetexsticky");` would be sufficient.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Well, i think i'm really stupid then.. I did the following:

Added in `<head>` the following:

`<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`

`<script type="text/javascript" src='/wp-content/plugins/icetex-sticky/assets/js/sticky.js'></script>`

Than, in the sticky.js document, i added the code. Is that wrong (sorry, not really a 'programmer')

Comment: As noted by TJ, `$this` should most likely be `this` if you absolutely must use the `each()` for some reason.  Otherwise just allow it to implicitly loop with the addClass method

Comment: OMG, i just forget the $(document).ready(function(){ tag. It is working now. THANKS!!

Answer (score 0):

Oh wow.. Maybe i had to do it right and add the $(document).ready(function(){... Totally forgot..

Solved with solution of TJ Crowder:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('[data-sticky~="1"]').addClass("icetexsticky");
});
```